# PHP условие по дням недели? как сделать?

Tags: php

вот примерно так, но немогу найти решение

```
if ($dayname == 'monday') {
echo $worktim_monday;
} elseif ($dayname == 'sunday') {
echo $worktime_sunday; }
```

но как вывести в переменную $dayname название дня недели на настоящий момент?

Comment: date('l')  Документация: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dayname = date('l');
```

Детальнее [про функцию date()](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/date.php).

ЗЫ. Однако слово возвращает с заглавной буквы. Например Monday.

Answer (score 1):

```
$worktime = [
    'Часы работы: Sunday', // воскресенье!
    'Часы работы: Monday',
    'Часы работы: Tuesday',
    'Часы работы: Wednesday',
    'Часы работы: Thursday',
    'Часы работы: Friday',
    'Часы работы: Saturday'
];

echo $worktime[date('w')];
```